# group values in csv file and save them in another csv file

Tags: python, csv

Hello I am trying to group my csv file only using the csv module and input the result in another csv file.
The problem that I am having is that the other fields get appended to the first field which is manufacturer and I want this to be done in the correct fields.
in `row[3]` the car_details are saved and in `row[4]` the car.
import csv

```
result = {}
fields=['test','name','object']

with open('work.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    writer = csv.writer(open("art1.csv",'w',newline=''), delimiter=';')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] in result:
          result[row[0]].append(row[3])
        else:
            result[row[0]] = [row[1]]
with open('art1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
   # writer.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in result.items():
        csvwriter.writerow(row)

reader = csv.reader(open("art1.csv", "r",newline=''), delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(open("artgain2.csv",'w',newline=''), delimiter=';')
writer.writerow(fields)
writer.writerows(reader)
```

the csv file:

```
toyota         fast           Prius
toyota         slow           yaris
toyota         fast           corolla
toyota         slow           sunshine
mercedes       fast           benz
mercedes       fast           something
mazda          fast           bus
```

the result I want

```
manufacturer   car_details    car
toyota         fast           Prius
               slow           yaris
               fast           corolla
               slow           sunshine
mercedes       fast           benz
               fast           something
mazda          fast           bus
```

the result I get:

```
manufacturer                      car_details    car
toyota,fast,Priusslow,yaris,fast,corolla,slow,sunshine,
mercedes,fast,benz,fast,something
mazda,fast,bus
```

Everything is in the manufacturer column and I dont know how to split this correctly in the corresponding fields
I feel that I am pretty close to the solution and I am probably forgetting something
Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you open your .CSV files with MS excel and you have a European language setting? The reason for this assumption is, that you seem to use ";" as separator in your output file.
So it seems reasonable that excel won't interpret your "," in your result files as separators. Additionally, it seems like you have no proper line breaks in your result file.

In all your files, I can't see any row with index 3 or 4. This seems to bee to high an index...

### Proposed solution

```
import csv

class ExcelEuropeDialect(csv.Dialect):
        delimiter      = ';'
        lineterminator = '\r\n'
        quotechar      = '"'
        quoting        = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL     
csv.register_dialect('excel_eu', ExcelEuropeDialect)

result = []
item_occured = [] # list with all items already occured
fields=['test','name','object']

with open('work.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[0] in item_occured:
            row[0] = ''                     # empty first cell
        else:
            item_occured.append(row[0]) # add item to item_occured
        row = [s.strip() for s in row]
        result.append(row)                  # append whole row
with open('art1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect=csv.get_dialect('excel_eu'))
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(result)
```

Comment: even if I set ";" to ",' it doesn't adds them all in the manufacturer column..

Comment: I edited my answer with a proposed solution. I think using the result list seperate from the already occured features list would benefit your cause. You should always append the whole row to "result" as you want the samme amount of fields in csv. You only have to empty the fist cell when the feature already occured

Comment: hello thanks for your answer :) I however get an error for `result.items():`which says 
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: My pleasure. Yes that probably results from your line "for row in result.items():" You can just write "for row in result:". Pleasy consider my above proposal contains just some corrections and comments about how to approach your issue. I hope you understand I could not test the code as it is on my side, because you did not provide the exact contents of the input file.

Comment: @Sevenito haha I just figured out the mistake at that moment . Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Happy to help. I just edited the code example above again to a fully working example. I did some lines a bit differently than your original approach.